# Laravel localise dates

Tags: php, laravel-5, localization

I'm trying to translate the (relatives) dates on my server but I can't find a way to do it.

Localization works well with standard date format, thanks to `'locale' => 'fr',` in my config file. But I'm using a relative date as a rule for a user creation:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
        'project-begin_at' => 'date_format:d/m/Y|required|after:yesterday',
    ]);
}
```

Which, when it fails, display:

[image]

`Yesterday` is not translated and it bugs me. I first supposed that I could use translation files like I did for `auth.php` & `validation.php` but I doesn't work.

### Update:

Here's the current `:after` string of `validation.php`:

```
'after' => 'Le champ :attribute doit être une date postérieure au :date.',
```

I could use the solution that @mpur provided but it would remove the dynamic around `:date` (If I change the rule to `after:today` I'll have to update all my translations and this sounds ugly)

How can I translate the relative dates?

Comment: What did you try to put in `validation.php`, because that really should be the way to do it?

Comment: @JoshRumbut see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this (according to the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-error-messages)), for example in `resources/lang/fr/validation.php` :

```
'custom' => [
    'project-begin_at' => [
        'after' => 'Le champ :attribute doit être une date postérieure à hier',
    ]
]
```

**UPDATE** :

I don't think you can do what you want because Laravel make a replace of `:date` with the raw value if `strototime(value) != false`

You can write something like this for more readability but it's not a tanslation :

```
public function rules()
{
    return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
        'project-begin_at' => 'date_format:d/m/Y|required|after:' . Carbon::yesterday(),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: That's what I'll do if I don't find any other way to do it.